# Get event when <video> is playing and when is paused when the video is loaded from a javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I have a html page that contains a javascript file. This .js file insert into the html the video player. I need to detect when the video is playing and when the video is paused, is possible to have an alert? For example: alert('Video is playing'); alert('Video is paused');

Unfortunately the video tag doesn't have any class or ID, for this the most of codes I've tried from stackoverflow.com doesn't work for me as I don't have any selector.

```html
<video width="600px" height="600px" preload="metadata"><source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

This code is not in the html file but is loaded into by an javascript file.

Comment: Running scripts you don't control is a dangerously bad idea... So take control over these, and add the event listeners as you've seen in other SO posts: when this element is being created.

Comment: Could you show the JS code you use to insert this video? It will allow us to give you a more fine tuned answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can refer to W3C [HTML DOM Video Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_video.asp)
 if you want to see if video is playng a solution is set a function in setInterval

```
var currTimeChk = 0;
setInterval(function(){

    var currTime = document.getElementById("vid").currentTime;

    if(currTime  != currTimeChk ){
        currTimeChk  = currTime;
        /* video is playing */
        alert('Video is playing');
    }else{
        /* video is paused*/
        alert('Video is paused');
    }
},100)
```

Comment: Thank you @Sim1-81, it was very helpful and works. I only make a small change because I doesn't have the Id selector on the video: document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0].currentTime;

Comment: This will only work, if there is only one video on the page or if the first video on the page is the one you are wanting to observe

Comment: if you have to add other videos keep in mind to introduce ID selector so you can check any video separately

Answer (score 2):

No jQuery is needed.

You add Event Listeners to every `video` element. If media events would bubble, then you only needed to listen to those event types on the `documentElement` and switch regarding the event's `target` node.

Since this is not possible you need to add the listeners to all existing `video` elements by walking the `HTMLCollection` (`[...document.getElementsByTagName('video')].forEach(/* ... */)`) and you need to add those listeners to every future `video` element. For this you need a `MutationObserver`

In this example I have two existing videos and two are added by JS (one with autoplay and one without respectively). I react on `play` and `pause` event and change the class of the video accordingly (play: green, paused: pink)

```js
"use strict";
console.clear();

{
  
  const events = ['play', 'pause']
  
  
  // Called upon play or pause event of video element
  function listener(e) {  
    e.target.classList.remove('playing');
    e.target.classList.remove('paused');
    switch(e.type) {
      case 'play':
        e.target.classList.add('playing');
        break;
      case 'pause':
        e.target.classList.add('paused');
        break;
    }
  }
  
  // Add Event Listeners to existing video elements
  [...document.getElementsByTagName('video')].forEach(v => {
    events.forEach(ev => v.addEventListener(ev, listener)) 
    
  })

  // called by MutationObserver
  // Adds Eventlisteners to newly inserted video elements
  
  
  function react(mutationList, observer) {
    [...mutationList].forEach(mr => {
      mr.addedNodes.forEach(node => {
        if (node.nodeType === 1 && node.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'video') {
          events.forEach(ev => node.addEventListener(ev, listener)) 
        }
      })
    })
  }

  
  const observer = new MutationObserver(react);
  const config = { childList: true, subtree: true };
  
  observer.observe(document.documentElement, config);

  
}



document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<video controls src=\"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/96344/SampleVideo_360x240_1mb.mp4\" width=\"360\" height=\"240\" autoplay muted playsinline></video>\n")

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<video controls src=\"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/96344/SampleVideo_360x240_1mb.mp4\" width=\"360\" height=\"240\"></video>\n")
```

```css
video {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 10px solid black;
}
video.playing {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-color: green;
}
video.paused {
  background-color: pink;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<video controls src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/96344/SampleVideo_360x240_1mb.mp4" width="360" height="240" autoplay muted playsinline></video>
<video controls src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/96344/SampleVideo_360x240_1mb.mp4" width="360" height="240"></video>
```

Comment: Though that goes for a debugging hack... This code should never make to production.

Comment: @Kaiido Please elaborate.

Comment: Having a Mutation Observer running in the wild in the hope of something like this to happen is only the sign of a very badly written web page. It's probably ok to use this for debugging, but any serious programmer will just fix the source of the problem: why don't they have control over when these elements are created?

Comment: The OP clearly states that they have no control over the video source. That's the situation. If you have any other idea how to listener to media element events, which are added by JS, then pleases go ahead and write an answer on your own.

Comment: But I agree that it could be more fine tuned. But there is no context in the OP that will allow me to do this.

Comment: If I would tell this to every Wordpress site owner ... *sigh*